# Is it possible to keep date's type when changing format?

Tags: node.js, date, format

I work with an API with nodeJS. It asks for a date (typeof myDate ==> date not string !) 'yyyy-mm-dd'. I am looking for solutions but i always find solutions to convert myDate into a string 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

I'm not sur it is possible. Is it possible ? If it is, how can i do ?

Thanks

Comment: if you use `json` to send your data to api, `json` doesn't have `Date` type and use `String` format of `Date`. you can send your `Date` in two way, 1) String formats ( `ISO`, etc) 2) `Timestamp`

Comment: Finally, i used string format and make it directly into the url (helped with querystring.stringify() method) and not into parameters. It works ^^. Thanks for your answer.